# WPF Binding comobox to another one

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have Two comboxboxes, one has the list of provinces and the other one should get filled with cities correspond to the selected province.
My problem is when ever I changed the province, the cities combox never get filled.

XML file:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProvincesCombo" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Provinces}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" > </ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="CitiesCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Cities, ElementName=ProvincesCombo}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
</ComboBox>
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Province> Provinces = new ObservableCollection<Province>();
Provinces.Add(new Province() { Name = "أدرار", Cities = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "تيط", "تيمقطن", "أقبلى", "أولف", "تبمياوين", "أوقروت", "أولاد السعيد", "تيميمون" } });
Provinces.Add(new Province() { Name = "الأغواط", Cities = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "الحاج المشري", "عين سيدي علي", "قلتة سيدي سعد", "الأغواط", "الخنق", "الحويطة" } });
DataContext = this;

public class Province
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the `ItemsSource` of the first combobox from `StaticResource` to `Binding` and changed the field `Provinces` to a property and all worked like expected.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProvincesCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Provinces}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" />
<ComboBox x:Name="CitiesCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Cities, ElementName=ProvincesCombo}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Provinces.Add(new Province() { Name = "A", Cities = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "City A1", "City A2" } });
    Provinces.Add(new Province() { Name = "B", Cities = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "City B1", "City B2" } });
}

public ObservableCollection<Province> Provinces { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Province>();
```

I also implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: It works now even I don't know where it was the issue in first place. I have another question, my source is defined as an array in app resources, how I can the two combobox linked?

Comment: You may forget to include `INotifyPropertyChanged` .

Comment: I would load the sources after initialization of the window/usercontrol

Comment: Where about INotifyPropertyChanged? Why you mentioned it?

Comment: Just to give you all information about my example :)